# Dynamically burn Feedburner feeds?

Tags: drupal, feedburner

We have a Drupal website with a seperate RSS feed for every blogger on the site.  There will be an indeterminate number of new users signing up and blogging in the future.  Drupal automatically generates an RSS feed for each new blog.  Is there a way to automatically burn each feed as well? We'd like to avoid manually adding a new feed to Feedburner every time a new user starts their blog.

Comment: Have you looked at the FeedBurner module? http://drupal.org/project/feedburner
I've never used it myself, so I can't say for sure if it will 'burn' the feeds for you or not. If it doesn't, I'd recommend submitting a feature request to the module's maintainer.

Comment: Thanks jhedstrom. I did look into the FeedBurner module actually, but its no help. All it really does is redirect requests for regular drupal rss feeds for Feedburner feeds, but you must set up these feeds beforehand in FeedBurner anyway. Good suggestion though- I'll submit a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the V[iews module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create an overall master view of all blog articles on your site, regardless of user.  E.g. Add the node title and user name fields and filter on node type = "Blog article".  Then, just create a feed display for this master view and burn that instead.